# A formula for my spreadsheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am pricing my services and packages in an Excel workbook and have come to a place beyond my Excel knowledge. In a worksheet called "Packages", I have columns for each different package I offer.  In the column I have dropdowns where one of any of my products can be selected (I have 13 different products).

What I want to do is have a formula that in cell A25 looks at cells A9:A21 and determines if there is any text, and then will take the cost corresponding the the product listed in said cell from the worksheet "Product Pricing" and will add all the values together. So, if A9 has product 1 and cost is $50, and A10 has Product 2 and cost is $75, and A11 is blank, I want the formula to make the value of A25 $125 (50+75).

I feel like it should be a bunch of nested IF and ISBLANK formulas, but I've only gotten part of the way through it and am being told "Formula is too long.  Formulas may not exceed 8,192 characters."  Is there another way I can do this?

Here is the formula I have written thus far:

```
=IF(ISTEXT(C9), IF(C9='Product Pricing'!$A$8,'Product Pricing'!$L$8+ IF(ISTEXT(C10), IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$8,'Product Pricing'!$L$8, IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$9,'Product Pricing'!$L$9,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$10,'Product Pricing'!$L$10,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$11,'Product Pricing'!$L$11,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$12,'Product Pricing'!$L$12,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$13,'Product Pricing'!$L$13,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$14,'Product Pricing'!$L$14,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$15,'Product Pricing'!$L$15,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$16,'Product Pricing'!$L$16,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$17,'Product Pricing'!$L$17,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$18,'Product Pricing'!$L$18,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$19,'Product Pricing'!$L$19,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$20,'Product Pricing'!$L$20, 0))))))))))))),0), IF(C9='Product Pricing'!$A$9,'Product Pricing'!$L$9+ IF(ISTEXT(C10), IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$8,'Product Pricing'!$L$8, IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$9,'Product Pricing'!$L$9,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$10,'Product Pricing'!$L$10,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$11,'Product Pricing'!$L$11,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$12,'Product Pricing'!$L$12,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$13,'Product Pricing'!$L$13,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$14,'Product Pricing'!$L$14,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$15,'Product Pricing'!$L$15,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$16,'Product Pricing'!$L$16,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$17,'Product Pricing'!$L$17,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$18,'Product Pricing'!$L$18,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$19,'Product Pricing'!$L$19,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$20,'Product Pricing'!$L$20, 0))))))))))))),0),  IF(C9='Product Pricing'!$A$10,'Product Pricing'!$L$10+ IF(ISTEXT(C10), IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$8,'Product Pricing'!$L$8, IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$9,'Product Pricing'!$L$9,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$10,'Product Pricing'!$L$10,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$11,'Product Pricing'!$L$11,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$12,'Product Pricing'!$L$12,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$13,'Product Pricing'!$L$13,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$14,'Product Pricing'!$L$14,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$15,'Product Pricing'!$L$15,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$16,'Product Pricing'!$L$16,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$17,'Product Pricing'!$L$17,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$18,'Product Pricing'!$L$18,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$19,'Product Pricing'!$L$19,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$20,'Product Pricing'!$L$20, 0))))))))))))),0),  IF(C9='Product Pricing'!$A$11,'Product Pricing'!$L$11+ IF(ISTEXT(C10), IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$8,'Product Pricing'!$L$8, IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$9,'Product Pricing'!$L$9,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$10,'Product Pricing'!$L$10,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$11,'Product Pricing'!$L$11,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$12,'Product Pricing'!$L$12,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$13,'Product Pricing'!$L$13,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$14,'Product Pricing'!$L$14,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$15,'Product Pricing'!$L$15,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$16,'Product Pricing'!$L$16,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$17,'Product Pricing'!$L$17,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$18,'Product Pricing'!$L$18,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$19,'Product Pricing'!$L$19,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$20,'Product Pricing'!$L$20, 0))))))))))))),0),  IF(C9='Product Pricing'!$A$12,'Product Pricing'!$L$12+ IF(ISTEXT(C10), IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$8,'Product Pricing'!$L$8, IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$9,'Product Pricing'!$L$9,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$10,'Product Pricing'!$L$10,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$11,'Product Pricing'!$L$11,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$12,'Product Pricing'!$L$12,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$13,'Product Pricing'!$L$13,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$14,'Product Pricing'!$L$14,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$15,'Product Pricing'!$L$15,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$16,'Product Pricing'!$L$16,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$17,'Product Pricing'!$L$17,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$18,'Product Pricing'!$L$18,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$19,'Product Pricing'!$L$19,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$20,'Product Pricing'!$L$20, 0))))))))))))),0),  IF(C9='Product Pricing'!$A$13,'Product Pricing'!$L$13+ IF(ISTEXT(C10), IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$8,'Product Pricing'!$L$8, IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$9,'Product Pricing'!$L$9,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$10,'Product Pricing'!$L$10,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$11,'Product Pricing'!$L$11,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$12,'Product Pricing'!$L$12,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$13,'Product Pricing'!$L$13,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$14,'Product Pricing'!$L$14,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$15,'Product Pricing'!$L$15,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$16,'Product Pricing'!$L$16,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$17,'Product Pricing'!$L$17,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$18,'Product Pricing'!$L$18,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$19,'Product Pricing'!$L$19,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$20,'Product Pricing'!$L$20, 0))))))))))))),0),  IF(C9='Product Pricing'!$A$14,'Product Pricing'!$L$14+ IF(ISTEXT(C10), IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$8,'Product Pricing'!$L$8, IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$9,'Product Pricing'!$L$9,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$10,'Product Pricing'!$L$10,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$11,'Product Pricing'!$L$11,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$12,'Product Pricing'!$L$12,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$13,'Product Pricing'!$L$13,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$14,'Product Pricing'!$L$14,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$15,'Product Pricing'!$L$15,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$16,'Product Pricing'!$L$16,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$17,'Product Pricing'!$L$17,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$18,'Product Pricing'!$L$18,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$19,'Product Pricing'!$L$19,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$20,'Product Pricing'!$L$20, 0))))))))))))),0),  IF(C9='Product Pricing'!$A$15,'Product Pricing'!$L$15+ IF(ISTEXT(C10), IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$8,'Product Pricing'!$L$8, IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$9,'Product Pricing'!$L$9,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$10,'Product Pricing'!$L$10,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$11,'Product Pricing'!$L$11,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$12,'Product Pricing'!$L$12,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$13,'Product Pricing'!$L$13,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$14,'Product Pricing'!$L$14,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$15,'Product Pricing'!$L$15,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$16,'Product Pricing'!$L$16,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$17,'Product Pricing'!$L$17,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$18,'Product Pricing'!$L$18,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$19,'Product Pricing'!$L$19,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$20,'Product Pricing'!$L$20, 0))))))))))))),0),  IF(C9='Product Pricing'!$A$16,'Product Pricing'!$L$16+ IF(ISTEXT(C10), IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$8,'Product Pricing'!$L$8, IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$9,'Product Pricing'!$L$9,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$10,'Product Pricing'!$L$10,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$11,'Product Pricing'!$L$11,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$12,'Product Pricing'!$L$12,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$13,'Product Pricing'!$L$13,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$14,'Product Pricing'!$L$14,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$15,'Product Pricing'!$L$15,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$16,'Product Pricing'!$L$16,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$17,'Product Pricing'!$L$17,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$18,'Product Pricing'!$L$18,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$19,'Product Pricing'!$L$19,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$20,'Product Pricing'!$L$20, 0))))))))))))),0),  IF(C9='Product Pricing'!$A$17,'Product Pricing'!$L$17+ IF(ISTEXT(C10), IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$8,'Product Pricing'!$L$8, IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$9,'Product Pricing'!$L$9,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$10,'Product Pricing'!$L$10,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$11,'Product Pricing'!$L$11,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$12,'Product Pricing'!$L$12,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$13,'Product Pricing'!$L$13,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$14,'Product Pricing'!$L$14,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$15,'Product Pricing'!$L$15,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$16,'Product Pricing'!$L$16,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$17,'Product Pricing'!$L$17,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$18,'Product Pricing'!$L$18,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$19,'Product Pricing'!$L$19,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$20,'Product Pricing'!$L$20, 0))))))))))))),0),  IF(C9='Product Pricing'!$A$18,'Product Pricing'!$L$18+ IF(ISTEXT(C10), IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$8,'Product Pricing'!$L$8, IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$9,'Product Pricing'!$L$9,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$10,'Product Pricing'!$L$10,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$11,'Product Pricing'!$L$11,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$12,'Product Pricing'!$L$12,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$13,'Product Pricing'!$L$13,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$14,'Product Pricing'!$L$14,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$15,'Product Pricing'!$L$15,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$16,'Product Pricing'!$L$16,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$17,'Product Pricing'!$L$17,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$18,'Product Pricing'!$L$18,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$19,'Product Pricing'!$L$19,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$20,'Product Pricing'!$L$20, 0))))))))))))),0),  IF(C9='Product Pricing'!$A$19,'Product Pricing'!$L$19 IF(ISTEXT(C10), IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$8,'Product Pricing'!$L$8, IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$9,'Product Pricing'!$L$9,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$10,'Product Pricing'!$L$10,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$11,'Product Pricing'!$L$11,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$12,'Product Pricing'!$L$12,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$13,'Product Pricing'!$L$13,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$14,'Product Pricing'!$L$14,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$15,'Product Pricing'!$L$15,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$16,'Product Pricing'!$L$16,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$17,'Product Pricing'!$L$17,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$18,'Product Pricing'!$L$18,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$19,'Product Pricing'!$L$19,  IF(C10='Product Pricing'!$A$20,'Product Pricing'!$L$20, 0))))))))))))),0),  IF(C9='Product Pricing'!$A$20,'Product Pricing'!$L$20, 0))))))))))))),0)
```

EDIT: Here are screenshots of the workbook

[image: This is the worksheet where the formulas need to go. One in each cell in row 24 and row 26.]

[image: This is the picture where we need to take the values from. The values for row 24 in the packages worksheet should come from column L, and the values for row 26 in the packages worksheet should come from column J.]

So, in these pictures, the cell C24 should equal, $1550.15, this would be the sum of cells 'Packages'!C8, 'Product Pricing'!L8, 'Product Pricing'!L11, and 'Product Pricing'!L13.

Comment: It seems that a [SUMIF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIF-function-169B8C99-C05C-4483-A712-1697A653039B) should be appropriate here but an example cannot be provided without sample data together with expected results.

Comment: I think a screenshot or replicating the spreadsheet here would really help us understand your problem. You didn't specify where the costs are and how to find them, besides naming the "Product Pricing" worksheet. What does the column I with the dropdowns have to do with the issue?
A formula like that one is obviously nonsense, it's non understandable and extremely hard to maintain. When things get too complicated, you should really look for an alternate way.
I think you probably need to use an auxiliary cell with `VLOOKUP` which will give you the product price, and then you just have to sum.

Comment: I added some pictures that hopefully show and explain what I'm trying to do.

Comment: One option - Add a column in Packages between E and F, and do a VLOOKUP to the Prices sheet to pull the price of each item into that column.  Then just Sum that to get the total, and hide the vlookup column to maintain the look of the sheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this as a Formula Array

```
=SUM(IF( $A$9:$A$21 <=0, 0, SUM(INDEX( 'Product Pricing'!$L$8:$L$20, 
MATCH( $A$9:$A$21, 'Product Pricing'!$A$8:$A$20, 0), 0))))
```

`$A$9:$A$21` is the range where you have the products listed (selection)

`'Product Pricing'!$L$8:$L$20` is the range that contains the prices in 
worksheet “Product Pricing”

`'Product Pricing'!$A$8:$A$20` is the range that contains the product codes in worksheet “Product Pricing”

Agree with @Andrew you should show the product prices besides each product then `SUM` all prices multiplied by the quantities, to show the prices use this formula besides each product *(remember to include the quantities)*:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP( A9, 'Product Pricing'!$A$8:$L$20, 12,0),"")
```

`'Product Pricing'!$A$8:$L$20` is the range that contains the products and prices 
`12` is the column within the above range where to pickup the prices

*Replace all ranges as needed*